# Working with OAuth python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, oauth

I'm am using OAuth to allow my user to OAuth with Hunch, on my webpage I have a button to allow the user to go to Hunch and enter their details

```
    <form action="/hunch" method="post" align = "right">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login using Hunch">
        </div>
    </form>
```

How can I call a method here rather than a handler? as it is currently calling this:

```
class hunch(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        url = 'http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=123&next=/get-recs'
        self.redirect(url)  
        logging.info("url2 = " + url2)

        auth_token_key = self.request.get('auth_token_key')
        logging.info("auth_token_key = " + auth_token_key)
```

but when I print the url2 it just prints /hunch? I hope this makes sense.

Also should this `auth_token_key = self.request.get('auth_token_key')` get information from the url that the user is directed to after they have entered their credentials?

Comment: Where does 'url2' come from? It's not mentioned anywhere in your code.

Comment: have you tried: http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2009/04/oauth-in-google-app-engine.html

Comment: @Nick Johnson sorry originally my code contained 
url2 = request.get(url) but this just returns the /hunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the documentation for [Hunch OAuth](http://hunch.com/developers/v1/docs/auth/).

Rather than intercepting the form on the backend, send the user directly to

> http://hunch.com/authorize/v1/?app_id=12345 (providing your own app_id and an optional next parameter).

If the user authorizes your application, they will be redirected to the `redirect_url` registered for your application along with an `auth_token_key`. For example, an app with a `redirect_url` of http://your-domain.com/authorized/ will be redirected to

> http://your-domain.com/authorized/?auth_token_key=7a1b2c3&auth_sig=941bc415af782a8d93a83c874922ae1b30e92a70

At this point you can exchange the `auth_token_key` for an `auth_token`.

The [Hunch sample app on Github](https://github.com/hunch/hunch-sample-app/blob/master/app/views.py) has an example of how this should be done. The `authorize` function generates a page asking the user to Hunch connect, and the `authorized` function exchanges the `auth_token_key` for an `auth_token`.

Answer (score 0):

When GAE (using OpenId) logs in a user, it relies on the `/_ah/login_required` page.

To get a user to enter their own credentials, you should create a page containing links to log in with the different providers you wish to use.  You must then override the `/_ah/login_required` mapping in your url mapping file to use your own custom login page rather than the default.

[This is a very good tutorial I used for this.](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Using-OpenID-authentication-on-App-Engine)

[Google now offers their own official tutorial.](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html)